# I am looking to call fragment functions from viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to call the functions frag.updateButtons() etc from within GameScreen (Main Activity) as ten times a second, the game cycles through these things and updates the variables accordingly.

The code is as it currently is. The frag.*** functions work when it is set up as a fragment, but now that I am wanting to use it as viewPager, it keeps having the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

I am fairly new to programming and Android code, and clearly don't entirely understand fragments and viewPager etc, so any help here would be very much appreciated.

I have not included the whole code, just the code that I think is relevant to the problem. If you need more code or info, please ask me and I'll get you what you need.

Thank you

```
public class GameScreen extends FragmentActivity implements GameScreenFragment.FragInterface{

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    GameScreenFragment frag;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.bottomFragment);
            /** set the adapter for ViewPager */
            mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

           startRepeatingTask();
           //the code here calls the mainLoop() function 10 times a second
        }
    }

    //for the fragment functions
    public void displayCompany(String companyName){}
    public void displayCompanyIncome(){}
    public void checkTeamImage(){}
    public void getCostOfEmployees(){}
    public void updateButtons(){}

    public void mainLoop(){
        //display company name and company income in fragment
        frag = (GameScreenFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottomFragment);
        frag.updateButtons();
        frag.displayCompanyIncome();
        frag.getCostOfEmployees();
        frag.displayCompany(Global.companyName[Global.companyNumber]);
        //updates the picture for that company
        frag.checkTeamImage();
    }
    public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            /** Show a Fragment based on the position of the current screen */
            Global.companyNumber = position;
            return new GameScreenFragment();

        }   

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }
    }

}
```

and then in the fragment whose ID in the .xml is bottomFragment

```
public class GameScreenFragment extends Fragment {

    FragInterface fragStuff;

    public interface FragInterface {
        void displayCompany(String companyName);
        void displayCompanyIncome();
        void checkTeamImage();
        void getCostOfEmployees();
        void displayCompanyName();
        void updateButtons();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_screen_fragment, container, false);

        //other code here
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the logcat here or atleast tell which line is throwing exception

Comment: I comment out all the frag.**** from within the mainLoop() and it works fine.
But when i have frag.updateButtons() active, it comes up with the error above

Comment: you should provide more info.. about your xml file and all the imports your are doing in your java file.